# Is it possible to define a nested schema with mutually exclusive fields in marshmallow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, marshmallow

I am using *marshmallow* to validate json data that I am receiving in a flask restful api. In the *post* request however there is a **mutually exclusive field**.
For example :
`{"predict": {"id": "5hgy667y4h7f"}}` or `{"predict": {"text": "This is a sample sentence"}}`
But **NOT** both `id` and `text` should be sent together. Moreover different methods are called based on weather `id` or `text` is received.

Q) How do I construct a schema in marshmallow that allows me to validate the above?

Sample code I have for either one of the fields is below -

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, abort
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, ValidationError
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Mutex1(Schema):
    text = fields.Str(required=True)
    class Meta:
        strict = True

class Mutex2(Schema):
    id_ = fields.Str(required=True)
    class Meta:
        strict = True

class MySchema(Schema):
    predict = fields.Nested(Mutex1)
    class Meta:
        strict = True

class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        input_req = request.get_json(force=True)
        try:
            result = MySchema().load(input_req)
        except ValidationError:
            return {'message': 'Validation Error'}, 500
        else:
            return {'message': 'Successful validation'}, 200

api.add_resource(Test, '/test')
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

This code accepts only `text`, and `text` with `id_`, however it rejects only `id_`. Any idea how to make it accept `id_` and reject both `text` and `id_` when passed together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Mutex` schema with both `text` and `id_` and add a [schema-level validation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/2.x-line/extending.html#schema-level-validation) to fail if both are provided.

```
class Mutex(Schema):

    @validates_schema
    def validate_numbers(self, data):
        if (
               ('text' in data and 'id_' in data) or
               ('text' not in data and 'id_' not in data)
           ):
            raise ValidationError('Only one of text and _id is allowed')

    text = fields.Str()
    id_ = fields.Str()
    class Meta:
        strict = True
```

Side notes:

- Input validation error should not return a 500 (server error) but a 422.
- I'm not familiar with flask-restful, but it looks like you could save yourself some boilerplate by using [webargs](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/webargs) to parse the resource inputs.

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't work. It gives validation error for any input given to it. I followed the link and I think the one [below it](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/2.x-line/extending.html#validating-original-input-data) is more like what i need.  However even with that I get validation error for any input. After that I removed `required=True` in class `Mutex`. This with the implementation of my link successfully distinguishes passing either one vs passing both. However it fails if I change the names of the parameters themselves like `text` becoming `ttest`. Any idea about this?

Comment: Right, you mest remove `required=True`, I didn't pay attention to that. Then you must modify the validator to also fail if none is provided. I fixed my answer about this.

Comment: You shouldn't need `pass_original` but maybe test `'text' in data` is not the right test. I'll double-check if I get the time.

Comment: What do you mean "change the names of the parameters"? If you change the names of the parameters of your resource, you need to adapt the schema and the validator. If you mean use a wrong name in the request, then the request will fail, which is correct.

Comment: I just double-checked and I think `'text' in data` is the right test and you don't need `pass_original=True`.

Comment: I tried the new solution and it works successfully for most of the part. I think i will accept your solution. However I must say that cases like `{"predict": {"text": "some text", "incorrect_id": "should not be here"}}` fail. I thought that `strict=True` should cover these cases but it doesn't seem to. Any idea why ?

Comment: `strict` means an Exception is raised if validation fails, rather than returning `data, error`. In marshmallow 3, all schemas are strict. What you want is fail on unknown fields. This is also default on marshmallow 3. Since you're using marshmallow 2, you have to do it manually, as shown in the docs about shema validation.

Comment: The issue with not passing `pass_original=True` is that whenever we pass incorrect fields only the correct ones make it to the `@validates_schema` decorator which kinda defeats the whole purpose. So now I modified the answer slightly and along with passing `pass_original = True` and it works just like I wanted it to.

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect that. Hopefully it will be peer reviewed and accepted.

Comment: Your edit was rejected and I understand that. Rejecting unknown fields is another question. Anyway, I'm glad your problem is solved.